# iOS: Wrong effect with "recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(..."

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

I am using the locationInView to set the position of my bouton when the user release it. After release, I give the location stored before but in fact, my button is not going back to the correct position.

This my code:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);

    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

    static CGPoint startLocation;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        startLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
        NSLog(@"Began: %d" @"-" @"%d", (int)startLocation.x , (int)startLocation.y);
    }

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        NSLog(@"Ended Bef: %d" @"-" @"%d", (int)startLocation.x, (int)startLocation.y);
        recognizer.view.center =  CGPointMake(startLocation.x, startLocation.y);

        startLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
        NSLog(@"Ended Aft: %d" @"-" @"%d", (int)startLocation.x, (int)startLocation.y);

    }

 }
```

In fact, the instruction:

```
recognizer.view.center =  CGPointMake(startLocation.x, startLocation.y);
```

give a wrong effect. Someone know why?

Comment: When the user drags a button I store the initial location of the button and when the user releases the button anywhere in the screen, I want to set the button back at the start location.

Comment: Thanks. The absence of the `static` was definitely confusing me.

Comment: why Rob? is it a bad choice to use static in this case?

Comment: No, in your original question you omitted the `static`. Thus, I couldn't see how the value was possibly being saved for you. With `static` it all now makes sense.

Comment: :) effectively, it's better like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. I'd suggest making sure you capture `startLocation` before you do any changing of the `center`.
2. You're using the location of the user's touch for `startLocation`. You really should initialize this with the `center` of the `recognizer.view`. It's exceedingly unlikely that the user started their gesture precisely in the center of the button. And as a result, you're unlikely to return back at the original location.

Somewhat unrelated, but:

1. You don't need to use `CGMakePoint` when resetting the `center` of `recognizer.view` in the `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` clause. You can use `CGPointMake` if you really want, but it's unnecessary. You can just use `startLocation`, if you want.
2. You might want to animate the returning of the view back to that `startLocation`. It's jarring to have it immediately go there.
3. As an aside, if you've saved `startLocation`, you don't need to continually reset the `translation`. Just use `startLocation` plus `translation`. Seems more clear to me, but clearly that's subjective.
4. I personally think `NSStringFromCGPoint` is very useful when logging `CGPoint` structures.

So, I'd suggest:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    static CGPoint startLocation;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        startLocation = recognizer.view.center;
        NSLog(@"Began: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(startLocation));
    }

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(startLocation.x + translation.x,
                                         startLocation.y + translation.y);

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        NSLog(@"Ended Bef: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(startLocation));

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                         animations:^{
                             recognizer.view.center = startLocation;
                         }];

        CGPoint finalLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
        NSLog(@"Ended Aft: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(finalLocation));
    }
}
```

Comment: waaaaaa, you really a genius !!!!!!! Many thx and in addition with all explanations!! Many thx again Rob!

Comment: I really need further practice to understand the powerful of the framework!! Many thx!