# iOS: Get Component ID in UIPanGestureRecognizer Event

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

Following a previous [unsuccessful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060112/ios-wrong-effect-with-recognizer-view-center-cgpointmake/), I want to try a new resolution of that issue by getting the ID of the component Recognizer when the (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer) method is called. Below my code:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

// Here, I want to get the ID of the recognizer eg: (a button.id)

}
```

Please, how can I do to catch the ID Object please.

Comment: Do you want the object that the user initially touched?  Or do you want the object that the user has panned to?

Comment: Yes, I want the component dragged by the user. In fact my context is, I have a screen with several buttons with the possibility to drag this buttons and I want the ID of the button dragged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know what you think an "id" is or what it might be good for. If you wish to know whether *this* object is the same object as *that* object, just compare them with the equality operator.

In `handlePan:`, the pan gesture recognizer is `recognizer`. Everything else you can readily obtain from there is a property of `recognizer`. For example, the view that is being panned (the touched view) is `recognizer.view`. Read the UIGestureRecognizer docs (and the UIPanGestureRecognizer docs) for a complete list.

Of course, this is your method, so if you have provided yourself with access to other information by way of properties, you can access those. For example, if `self` is MyViewController, then you have access to all the properties, public and private, of MyViewController.

Comment: impeccable. I found with: NSString *id = recognizer.view.restorationIdentifier;
Thx Matt!

Comment: I certainly cannot recommend misusing `restorationIdentifier` as some kind of object identifier. As I said before, the object *is* its own unique identifier, and can be compared directly with other objects to learn which of them is this object.

Comment: hmm ok, so what is the key property of the object and which method is used to access it?

recognizer.view.[keyProperty] ?

Comment: I do not know what "id" or "key property" mean (to you) or why you think you need them. Can you explain what you want to do?